# Cannot get body element from ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

The response is a HTML document (from a request from a link's href)

```
 var data = $(response).find('body').html();
 alert(data);  

 // I get a alert with nothing...
```

full code:

```
     $.ajax({
       url: $(this).attr('href'),
       type: 'GET',      
       success: function(response){
         var data = $(response).find('body').html();
         alert(data);  
        }
     });
```

Comment: Does the response contain `body` element?

Comment: @BiberFiver: Does `alert(response)` output anything?

Comment: yes, the entire html, yes it has the body in it, it's normal html page

Comment: can you try to alert data to see what is the response, or if you are using firebug you can see it in response tab

Comment: first try to console.log($(response)) and check if it is one that you expect

Comment: @Senad: That is what he did and he got nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this tricky code ;)

```
   /*this will get the body content and head by replacing them with div before placing them inside the jQuery factory witch will avoid all bugs, i used this while creating the ajaxit jquery plugin :) */
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: $(this).attr('href'),
                async:true,
                error:function (event, request, options, error) {
                    if (ajaxItMain.onError){
                        ajaxItMain.onError(event,request,options,error);
                    }
                },
                success:  function (data) {
                    // ----------------- < data >
                    // clearing CDATA
                    data=data.replace(/\<\!\[CDATA\[\/\/\>\<\!\-\-/gi,'');
                    data=data.replace(/\/\/\-\-\>\<\!\]\]\>/gi,'');

                    // extracting the the head and body tags
                    var dataHead = data.match(/<\s*head.*>[\s\S]*<\s*\/head\s*>/ig).join("");
                    var dataBody = data.match(/<\s*body.*>[\s\S]*<\s*\/body\s*>/ig).join("");
                    var dataTitle = data.match(/<\s*title.*>[\s\S]*<\s*\/title\s*>/ig).join("");

                    dataHead  = dataHead.replace(/<\s*head/gi,"<div");
                    dataHead  = dataHead.replace(/<\s*\/head/gi,"</div");

                    dataBody  = dataBody.replace(/<\s*body/gi,"<div");
                    dataBody  = dataBody.replace(/<\s*\/body/gi,"</div");

                    dataTitle = dataTitle.replace(/<\s*title/gi,"<div");
                    dataTitle = dataTitle.replace(/<\s*\/title/gi,"</div");


                    // comments
                    var commentPattern = /\<\!\-\-([\s\S]*?)\-\-\>/ig;

                    // get head comment tags
                    var headComments = dataHead.match(commentPattern);

                    // get body comment tags
                    var bodyComments = dataBody.match(commentPattern);

                    // head - body - title content
                    var $dataHead    = $(dataHead);
                    var $dataTitle   = $(dataTitle);
                    var $dataBody    = $(dataBody);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: you can include them in the same way ;) , but i didn't do this because once you add the head html or body html into the document this will execute all the javascript

Comment: It is NOT SAFE to blindly modify HTML with regexp replacements.

Answer (score 12):

Try it this way:

```
var $dom = $(document.createElement("html"));
$dom[0].innerHTML = response;

var $body = $dom.find("body");
```

Comment: Definitely the better solution here.

Comment: Worked out that IE9 doesn't like this. Abort!

Answer (score 1):

Passing string which represents an entire HTML document into the jQuery factory results in a collection containing many of the tags from within the string, not a single element representing a total page.

You need to create a DOM document out of the markup, and pass that into jQuery.

As a starter, you could try telling `$.ajax` that you're expecting back XML so that it is parsed into a DOM Document for you. However, the resulting DOM document would not allow for methods such as `.html()` to be called against it as it would not be considered HTML.

Comment: See my edited response. Getting a document is easy, but knowing how to work with it will be tricky.  Perhaps you could receive the response back as text and try to write it to an invisible iframe and then navigate it...yuck.