# How to add result of html page which contains jquery scripts in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm getting result of html page which contains Jquery scripts.
I'm loading this html in iframe and the jquery is not loaded

```
$("#getQesAnsButton").click(function() {
    $.get("/getQesAns", function(data, status) {
        $("#Qs").contents().find("body").html(data);
        //$("#Qs").contents().find("html").html(data);
    });
});
```

The html I'm getting (in 'data') looks:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#buttonSubmit").click(function() {
                console.log("Button Clicked");
            });
        })
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="formQues1" action="">
        <legend> Q# 1 </legend>
        <input type="radio" name="rad" value="1"> Q1A1
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="rad" value="2"> Q1A2
        <br> </form>
    <form id="formQues2" action="">
        <legend> Q# 2 </legend>
        <input type="radio" name="rad" value="1"> Q2A1
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="rad" value="2"> Q2A2
        <br> </form>
    <button id="buttonSubmit"> Submit </button>
</body>

</html>
```

- As you can see I have tried to load the iframe with find("html") but I'm getting same results
- if it's matter the main page (the page which contains the iframe I'm trying to load to) contains JQuery scripts in his head.

How can I load the html page I'm getting in 'data' varable (which contains JQuery scripts in his head) into iframe and the scripts will be loaded ?

Comment: Are you asking how to change the entire body of a loaded iframe, leaving its `head` data intact? This sounds fraught with privacy and cross-browser restriction issues. What are you trying to achieve? what are you trying to replace the body of an iframe instead of loading one you control? why cant you get the scripts the other iframe is loading yourself, and load them into your new iframe?

Comment: the Iframe contains a result of other user actions. the iframe will be used (with all the logic) later to send results of forms into the server

Comment: if you're in control of the original iframe's code, and you're looking at replacing the entire body. you should be able to create another iframe entirely with the correct body and head already. As a general rule of thumb, you cannot talk into or out of an iframe easily, and especially not if it you're trying to replace the entire body. Simple messaging is possible, but you're probably approaching your problem the wrong way. Can you explain in your question more specifically why you're trying to do what you want please.

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part is that you should get the response as string replace every script tag into something else before using it check my answer to this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7002297/427622

Note: when you append the string to the iframe using JQuery it will first convert the string into JQuery object this will force the JQuery to evaluate all the JavaScript tags witch will make it evaluated in the main page before it is even appended to the iframe