# After getting a page's content from an AJAX request I can select tag element but cannot select body element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I got an html page through an AJAX request

```
$.ajax({
    async: true,
    method: 'GET',
    url: linkPage,
    // cache: true,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

The data format I get like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body id="sustainable" class='sustainable'>
<div id="wrap">
    <main class="temp>
        <section class="sec01">
            ...
        </section>
    </main>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I want to get the body id and class (which is ***"sustainable"***) via this code:

```
$(data).find('body').attr('class');
```

But I have no idea why I can't get that, it returns ***undefiend***. But when I get html content or class of `<main>` by this code:

```
$(data).find('main').attr('class');
$(data).find('main').html();
```

It returns exactly what I want. Can anybody explain me why?

I've tried some solutions so far by create a virtual DOM like this, and I can select `<body>` and `<main>` from AJAX data as I want: [Cannot get body element from ajax response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001926/cannot-get-body-element-from-ajax-response)

But I still wonder why I can't select `<body>` class and html as first case?

Comment: Have you tried using document.getElementById("sustainable"); ?  Or with JQuery $("#sustainable") using its id or $(".sustainable") using the class name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work the way you tried is explained in the jQuery [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2):

> If the HTML is more complex than a single tag without attributes, as it is in the above example, the actual creation of the elements is handled by the browser's `.innerHTML` mechanism. In most cases, jQuery creates a new `<div>` element and sets the `innerHTML` property of the element to the HTML snippet that was passed in.

Since you can't have a `<body>` inside a `<div>`, the browser ignores the `<body>` tag.

The documentation goes on to say:

> When passing in complex HTML, some browsers may not generate a DOM that exactly replicates the HTML source provided. As mentioned, jQuery uses the browser's `.innerHTML` property to parse the passed HTML and insert it into the current document. During this process, some browsers filter out certain elements such as `<html>`, `<title>`, or `<head>` elements. As a result, the elements inserted may not be representative of the original string passed.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. But in my case, I cannot select `<div id="wrap">` too. Do you know why?

Comment: After filtering out the elements it can't use, that `<div>` becomes a top-level element in the collection. `.find()` only searches descendants, it doesn't match the element itself.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like, when given a string like that, jQuery will only save the *contents of the body* into its collection:

```js
const data = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body id="sustainable" class='sustainable'>
<div id="wrap">
    <main class="temp>
        <section class="sec01">
            ...
        </section>
    </main>
</div>
</body>
</html>`;
console.log($(data)[0]);
console.log($(data)[1]);
console.log($(data)[2]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

(Check your browser console. It's selecting the text nodes around `#wrap`, and `#wrap` itself, but *not* the `<head>` or `<body>`)

You could use DOMParser instead, which will try to turn the *whole string* into a document, without trying to leave things out:

```js
const data = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body id="sustainable" class='sustainable'>
<div id="wrap">
    <main class="temp>
        <section class="sec01">
            ...
        </section>
    </main>
</div>
</body>
</html>`;
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(data, 'text/html');
console.log(doc.body.className);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Another benefit of using DOMParser is that, unlike jQuery, it won't execute possibly-unsafe code in the HTML string:

```js
const data = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body id="sustainable" class='sustainable'>
<img src onerror="alert('evil')">
</body>
</html>`;
$(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
jQuery version, unsafe
```

```js
const data = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body id="sustainable" class='sustainable'>
<img src onerror="alert('evil')">
</body>
</html>`;
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(data, 'text/html');
console.log(doc.body.className);
```

```html
DOMParser version, safe
```

Answer (score 0):

The following jQuery Won't work:

```
$(data).find('sustainable');
```

as the divs are top level elements and data isn't an element but a string, to make it work you need to use .filter

```
$(data).filter('sustainable.wrap');
```

Comment: I've tried to use filter so far by this: `$(data).filter('body').attr('class');` but it doesn't work.