# Get <html> class from ajax response with filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, filter

I need to get the  class from a $.get but I don't know how.

Example:

```
<html lang="eng" class="hello">
```

I want to get the hello

Here is what I do:

```
$.get('somelink',function(data){var htmlClass = $(data).filter('html').attr('class')});
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: The jQuery collection won't find the `<html>` - I'd use [DOMParser instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59624026). `const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(data, 'text/html');
const htmlClass = doc.documentElement.className;`

Comment: Thanks, that was the solution I needed